# How do I put Qt in path for Visual Studio Code with Windows?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code

```
#include <QApplication>
```

Gives me the squiggles and compiling gives me an error.

```
fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory #include <QApplication>
```

My c_cpp_properties.json file looks like this

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\Qt\\6.1.0\\mingw81_64\\include\\QtWidgets\\**" // line I added
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I can see that the 'qapplication.h' and 'QApplication' files are inside that QtWidgets folder that I point to. I'm confused as to why Code can't find it.

btw, QtCreator works on this machine. But I would like to use VSC instead for a couple reasons.

Comment: Why don't you use cmake? I point this out because Qt is a complex project and a simple configuration (Makefile) is not easy to implement.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how CMake works... Does it somehow override the includePath set in the c_cpp_properties file? I looked at the retifrav github page about CMake with Code but it's not clear to me how this all works. And I'd also like to know why the above DOESN'T work.

Comment: In fact, I didn't think that I wasn't using CMake. I have a CMakeLists.txt file in my project  folder.

Comment: 1) Cmake allows you to configure includepaths, libs, defines, etc. similar to what qmake does, instead you are defining it in c_cpp_properties.json so you are not using cmake. I recommend you review a tutorial that indicates how to use mingw + cmake with vscode in windows. And after creating a Hello world then check the official Qt + CMake example so you know how to implement the example in your case

Comment: 2) For simple projects using c_cpp_properties.json is an option (this is similar to the complexity of a Makefile) but for complex projects it is no longer so, that is why Qt offers qmake, qbs or cmake to do such tasks.

Comment: I would love to use cmake, but our project doesn't use it...